# Reference about conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I am here because I want to know if someone knows of some good e fast books or references about conformal map . More precisely I need of the propeties of the conformal maps on manifolds with boundary. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Invariant Operators on Conformal Manifolds by Jan Slovák is available online: http://www.math.muni.cz/~slovak/ftp/papers/vienna.ps